# Are any pair of homotopic diffeomorphisms isotopic?

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology

Let $f_0, f_1:M\to N$ be two $C^k$ diffeomorphisms homotopic via a continuous homotopy $H_t$. We can approximate the homotopy by a smooth homotopy $\tilde{H}_t$ rel $\{0,1\}$.

If $M$ is compact, then since $\text{Diff}^k(M,N)$ is open in $C_S^k(M,N)$, it follows that $\tilde{H}_t \in \text{Diff}^k(M,N)$ if $t$ is sufficiently close to $0$ or $1$ since $\tilde{H}_0 = f_0, \tilde{H}_1 = f_1$. I *think* compactness of $M$ is needed in this last step, since then the weak and strong topologies agree.

Is it possible to choose the homotopy $\tilde{H}_t$ so that $\tilde{H}_t \in \text{Diff}^k(M,N)$ for *all* $t \in [0,1]$? Does the answer depend on whether or not $M$ is compact?

Comment: No, homotopy does not imply isotopy in general, even in compact case.

Comment: @MoisheCohen thanks for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are few things to know:

1. If two homeomorphisms (diffeomorphisms) of closed 2-dimensional manifolds are homotopic then they are isotopic (smoothly isotopic); this is due to D.B.A.Epstein, 1966.
2. If you do not assume that the surface is closed then the following is a counter example: $f(z)=1/\bar{z}$, the inversion of the punctured complex plane ${\mathbb C}^*$. It is homotopic but not isotopic to the identity map.
3. For closed aspherical 3-dimensional manifolds, homotopic homeomorphisms (diffeomorphisms) are isotopic (smoothly isotopic). A reference for this is a bit painful to trace, since it is scattered between several papers (Haken case is due to Waldhausen, I think; hyperbolic case is due to Gabai, etc.), the hardest part of the proof is Perelman's Geometrization Theorem.
4. For general closed 3-dimensional manifolds, homotopy does not imply isotopy, see  J. L. Friedman, D.M. Witt, [Homotopy is not isotopy for homeomorphisms of 3-manifolds](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/John_Friedman2/publication/256364564_Homotopy_is_not_isotopy_for_homeomorphisms_of_3-manifolds/links/00b7d533d7f2b5c668000000.pdf?origin=publication_detail),  Topology 25 (1986), no. 1, 35–44. (The same in the smooth category.)
5. Probably the most famous example is in dimension 6, due to Milnor: There are diffeomorphisms of 6-dimensional sphere which are continuously isotopic but not smoothly isotopic.  (Gluing two copies of the 7-ball via such diffeomorphisms results in exotic 7-spheres.)

Comment: These were really helpful for me. Thanks a lot.